# How to "manipulate" using R in Emacs

Tags: ess, r

In Rstudio one can use library `manipulate` to interactively change the plot over some parameters(mu). When you use this in emacs ESS it gives error:

```
function(mu){
plot(mu)
}
manipulate(myfunc(mu),mu = slider(1,100,step=0.5))
```

**Error**

```
Error in manipulate(myfunc(mu), mu = slider(1, 100, step = 0.5)) : 
The manipulate package must be run from within RStudio
```

Is there a way around to get this library to work in ESS EMACS? Please help! Thanks! I searched on google but there is not one article related to this!

P.S
I have Emacs 24 on ubuntu 16, I have some basic experience with init.el files where I customize by taking code from around the internet.

Comment: Well, it is designed to work within RStudio. This is what the Error is aying and also the manual. I guess ESS will run everything that would work from the terminal but this is not the case here.

Comment: Right! is there anything I can do to make something "similar" work? @andrej within the emacs ESS of course!

Comment: I'm not aware of such a package for ESS. Maybe someone else knows better. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23597415/interactive-graphics-in-ess-with-manipulate-package

Comment: Checked it. Sounds way too compliated! Thanks!